# Mongoose query conditionally exclude fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query which excludes fields; however, I'd only like to exclude them if they are empty. Currently I have:

```
var query = Recipe.find({'sites': site})
            .select('-data.coupons');
```

I would like to only exclude the selected field `'-data.coupons'` if it matches this condition: `.where({ 'data.coupons': {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}} });`

Is there a way to only conditionally exclude the `'-data.coupons'` field if it matches a condition?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to exclude fields from the returned Mongo documents themselves? Or exclude entire documents that match the condition?

Comment: I'd like the document to not be excluded, just those fields on the document that meat the condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to conditionaly exclude non-_id field from a query. If you try to do this, mongo shell will return following error:

> The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for
>   exclusion

You can check documentation for [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator.

But you can try something with aggregate:

```
Recipe.aggregate([
        {$match: {'sites': site}},
        {$project:{
            data.coupons:{$cond:[ { '$eq': [ '$data.coupons', [] ] }, [], '$data.coupons' ]}
        }},
    ],function(err, recipes){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }else{
            //remove all data.coupons that have value equal to 0
        }
    });
```

Query will return data.coupons filed but will set its value to empty array if it meets condition. You can then remove data.coupons field with length equal to 0.

Comment: I'm returning MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$exists'

Comment: There was a syntax error in $project specification, I edited my answer.

Comment: still, the same error. It looks like $exist may not be valid with $project

Comment: You are right, $exist is "query" operator and it should not be used for logical  condition. Try using $ifNull or $eq operator to edit your condition.

Comment: That gets me a lot closer, thanks. I just need to figure out a way to target empty arrays instead of null.

Comment: You can just add [] into $eq expression